# RSA Encryption process in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, rsa

In an effort to understand the asymmetric encryption process I outlined a simple PHP script to encrypt and decrypt simple numbers. I noticed that after a while given numbers to encrypt/decrypt the algorithm would fail, as in the decrypted and initial numbers didn't match. I put a loop in to see how the algorithm would perform when ecrypting and decrypting 100 numbers and after the number 32 the process fell apart.

Is this because p*q = 33?

```
<?php

# Test encrypto algo

// Choose prime keys
$p = 47; $q = 71; 
// Compute n = pq
$n = $p*$q;
// Choose e such that 1 < e < f(n) and e and n are coprime
$e = 79;
// Compute a value for d such that (d * e) % f(n) = 1
$d = 1019;
// Compute f(n) = (p-1)(q-1)
$z = ($p - 1)*($q - 1);
// Create public and private keys
$pubK = array('n' => $n, 'e' => $e);
$privK = array('n'=> $n, 'd' => $d);
// Boundary for loop
$l = 100;

// Perform encypt/decrypt on 1..100
for($i = 1; $i <= $l; $i++)
{
    $enc = enc($i, $pubK);
    $dec = dec($enc, $privK);
    print "encrypted <b>$i</b> = $enc decrypted $enc = <b>$dec</b> ";
    if($i == $dec)
        print "Success<br>";
    else
        print "Fail<br>";
}

// Encrypt sample with public key
function enc($sample, $key)
{
    return bcmod(bcpow($sample,$key['e']),$key['n']);
}
// Decrypt encrypted sample with private key
function dec($sample, $key)
{
    return bcmod(bcpow($sample, $key['d']),$key['n']);
}

?>
```

[image: Output from the loop]

Comment: set `$p` to 5 and look what happens. I think the problem is in small p and `q` numbers. Script should fail then on 54 iteration

Comment: You're right. I set p and q to 3 and 5 and it failed on 14, which supports (3*5) - 1.

Comment: well $key['n'] = 33  (cause 3*11) and it fails on 33...

Comment: Ok maybe your algorithm is wrong. Are you spliting your `$i` into values smaller than `n`?

Comment: I think the question has been answered. The keys provide a range, so they need to be larger. On a similar note, when I use larger keys PHP gives `NAN`, numbers too big?

Comment: @lee i never heard about relationship between size of `p` `q` and size of input data. Please check your algorithm one more time.

Comment: I'm following the example outlined here http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~mitra/honors/soln.html I've updated my algo for clarity, it looks ok to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(algorithm)

> **2.2 Encryption:**
>
> [...] Bob then wishes to send message M to Alice. He
>   first turns M into an integer m, such that **0 ≤ m < n** by using an
>   agreed-upon reversible protocol known as a padding scheme. ...Alice transmits her public key (n, e) to Bob and keeps the

This does not hold here, therefore you need to use larger factorizations.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in small `$p` and `$q` values. As we noticed in comments, bigger value of `$n=$p*$q` starts returning fails later.

Problems start when `$i>$n`, then encription/decription returns wrong numbers.

What to do?
In real problems, `$p` and `$q` are huge numbers. Also message is splited into smaller one and provides as stream of many values. For example you can decrypt parts of your number, and then sum it to get final value. In  more advanced cases, code every symbol as a number, and encode/decode they one by one.

Comment: That makes sense. However, in PHP when I use larger keys - say 47 and 71 - everything returned is `nan` I take it they're too big for integer space?

Comment: use the BCMath or GMP extension then.

Comment: then `pow($sample,$key['e'])` returns huge number. You can repair it spliting your `$i` into smaller parts.